# How to easily get the order of numbers saved as strings on android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have around 50 Strings in an Array `B[]` that contain a number with 2 decimals. I want to display them in a recyclerView sorted by biggest to smallest, so I need to make another Array that contains their order. I can't just change their order as each of them has also a Name in `N[]` that needs to be at the same position. Should I use an SQLite command or just make a function that sorts them one by one? Or, in the best case, is there a way to use `sort()` or a similar command to sort an array `O[]` containing 50 Numbers 1-50  but sorting by the values of `B[]`?

If not, I would probably clone the Array `B[]` to `C[]` and then `sort(C[])`. Then I would:

```
for (i = 0,j != 50, i++) {
   for(j = 0, j!= 50, j++) {
      if(C[i].equalsTo(B[j]) {
      O[i]=j
      break;
   }
}
```

Anything wrong with that? Or any suggestions?

As an example: `B[ ]` is:

```
5.26 1.75 9.45 16.74 3.65 0.54 7.21
```

then `O[ ]` should have the values

```
5 1 4 0 6 2 3
```

Comment: can you provide an example input of data and what you expect the output to be? sounds like streams would be useful here but can you provide what I have mentioned?

Comment: can you write the example input and expected output within your post?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw added one, just with less values. I suppose this works, but is there anything better performance wise?

Comment: your example doesn't match what you've stated above it. you said you want to order the " b[ ] " from largest to smallest and yet your expected output doesn't meet that criteria and also removes the decimal places. consider narrowing down your questions to 1-2 and give appropriate expected input and expected output.

Comment: No I want an array that tells me the order of B[ ] from smallest to biggest or the other way around. As B[5] is the smallest vallue of B[ ], O[0] is 5

Comment: alright okay, so you want a new array containing the index of the elements of the b [ ] from largest to smallest value or vice versa.

Comment: Exactly. I don't care is it is from the largest to smallest of the other way around as I can easily reverse it.

I also don't care if I use Arrays or SQL.

Comment: see my answer, I will update it in a few minutes to provide more detail about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a custom POJO to contain a decimal/name pair, define a custom comparator, and then sort a collection using it.  Something like this:

```
public class Dpair {
    double value;
    String name;

    public static Comparator<Dpair> DpairComparator
                      = new Comparator<Dpair>() {

        public int compare(Dpair dp1, Dpair dp2) {
            return Double.compare(dp1.getValue(), dp2.getValue());
        }
    };
    // getters and setters
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dpair[] array = new Dpair[7];
        array[0] = new Dpair(5.26d, "name1");
        array[1] = new Dpair(1.75d, "name2");
        array[2] = new Dpair(9.45d, "name3");
        array[3] = new Dpair(16.74d, "name4");
        array[4] = new Dpair(3.65d, "name5");
        array[5] = new Dpair(0.54d, "name6");
        array[6] = new Dpair(7.21d, "name7");

        // now sort your array of custom pairs on the value
        // this will bring the names with it, maintaining the relative positioning
        Arrays.sort(array, Dpair.DpairComparator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the `Collections.sort()` method but provide your own algorithm to compare the items within your array.

The solution below uses some helper lists in order to sort the initial array without actually changing the initial array hence why we used a helper list.

**input data:**

```
String[] b =  {"5.26", "1.75", "9.45", "16.74", "3.65", "0.54", "7.21"}; // assuming this is array "b"
int[] indexArray = getIndexOfSortedArray(b); // retrieved index values are stored within the indexArray
```

**method algorithm:**

```
public int[] getIndexOfSortedArray(String[] b){
    List<String> bList = Arrays.asList(b);  // helper list
    List<String> HelperList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(b,b.length)); // helper list
    int[] indexArray = new int[b.length]; // this contains the index values

    Collections.sort(HelperList, (fItem, sItem) -> Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(fItem),Double.parseDouble(sItem)));
    for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
        indexArray[i] = bList.indexOf(HelperList.get(i));
    }

    Arrays.stream(indexArray).forEach(System.out::println); // just for testing purpose, you may remove if you wish to...
    return indexArray; // return the index array 
}
```

**data output:**

```
[5, 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 3]
```